# Rails SQL SERVER: RuntimeError: Unknown bind columns. We can account for this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am getting this error: RuntimeError: Unknown bind columns. We can account for this.

I am on Rails 4.1 and connecting to a SQL SERVER 2005.

Here's what I set up for the Job model based on the database.

```
class JobTable < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "JobTable"
  self.primary_key = "JobId"

  has_many :job_products

end
```

Here's what I set up for the Product model based on the database.

```
class JobProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "JobProduct"
  self.primary_key = "ItemId"

  belongs_to :job_table

end
```

Both the primary keys are strings from the database.

I am trying to execute JobTable.first.job_products and I am getting that error. Any idea why?

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought on the matter is that you need to specify which foreign key you are referring to on both tables. When you say `has_many :job_products` a few things are assumed and two of them is that the model (class_name) will be called `Job_product`, and that a record on this table will possess the foreign key called `job_table_id`.

So, to fix your issue, I would try the following:

### models/JobTable.rb

```
class JobTable < ActiveRecord::Base

...

has_many :job_products, class_name: 'JobProduct', foreign_key: 'JobId'

...

end
```

### models/JobProduct.rb

```
class JobProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

...

belongs_to :job_table, class_name: 'JobTable', foreign_key: 'JobId'

...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the `class_name` on your `belongs_to` and specify the `foreign_key`'s on both models. I am not sure exactly how to do this but here's an example:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/6429700-runtimeerror-unknown-bind-columns-we-can-account-for-this

```
User.rb
   has_many  :filings, foreign_key: 'owner_id'
Filing.rb
   belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
```

Make sure to also refer to the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) Self Joins section.